# Как в си посимвольно читать поток ввода до последнего символа?

Tags: c

Как в си посимвольно читать поток ввода до последнего символа? Проблема в том, что если мы читаем с файла, скажем функцией getc(), мы можем читать до константы eof, но при чтении той же функции с потока ввода, такой метод не работает. Как я понимаю, когда нажимается enter, в поток ввода печатается \n,можно было бы читать до этого символа, но проблема в том, что этот символ может встретиться в середине текста, по этому такой метод не подходит

Comment: У потока ввода тоже бывает eof

Comment: @Denver Toha можно воспользоватся библиотекой [readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)

Comment: @Yaroslav, к сожалению мне необходимо читать по символьно

Comment: Решите для себя, как вы хотите определить **конец ввода**. Если вы хотите читать поток ввода с клавиатуры - **КАК** вы определите (для себя!) что вот он, конец, ура?... Дайте ответ на этот вопрос - и все станет сразу понятно.